# Protecting private keys of common chat applications with 2FA

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, multi-factor

Say a user uses a common chat application like Telegram, Signal, Whatsapp, Ricochet.
His device gets hacked and private keys get stolen. For normal PGP usage with email you can use two factor authentication and store the key on a yubikey for instance. Is something similar possible with those chat programs, i.e. a 2FA device needs to be plugged in all the time and without it no chatting is possible?

Comment: Are you asking about on desktop or on mobile? Because those apps are mostly used on mobile, where the device itself is frequently considered one auth factor, and where it's hard to tamper with the file system. On desktop, it's quite easy; just store the file with the key on an encrypted flashdrive.